# How to ensure a remote git user executes certain commands in a post-receive hook?

Tags: git, permissions, github-pages, git-post-receive

Hopefully I don't butcher this explanation of my setup. I am currently calling `git push` to a bare repo on a remote machine to trigger a post-receive hook that looks like so:

```
cd /path/to/working/tree
git pull
gatsby build && gh-pages -d public/
```

Everything works as expected up until the deploy step where `gh-pages` pushes the changes to GitHub Pages, through another repo on GitHub. I get a `remote: Permission denied (publickey)` when the post-receive hook is triggered via a `git push` from my local machine, however it succeeds when run on the remote machine directly.

I'm guessing that the execution of `gh-pages` is being done by a different user when the hook is triggered from my local machine, despite my `git remote` configuration specifying the correct remote user.

```
staging [remote_user]@[remote_ip]:/path/to/bare/repo.git (fetch)
staging [remote_user]@[remote_ip]:/path/to/bare/repo.git (push)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm guessing that the execution of gh-pages is being done by a different user when the hook is triggered from my local machine

You could check that, by modifying the post-receive hook and add to it:

```
id -a
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

That way, you will see exactly what id, and what SSH keys are considered on that hook.

Comment: Thank you! This showed that git was defaulting to trying `id_rsa.pub`, but the key was named something else.